Apache ServerName with protocol
I have this custom.conf for a Apache Docker container
ServerName https://staging.smartreparatur.at

# Enable Gzip compression (Deflate)
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
DeflateCompressionLevel 9
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/html>
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

# Enable caching for static assets
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


# Security headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
#        Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>


# Enable logging
# Log to standard output (stdout)
CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2

it's for an Apache Docker container behind a reverse proxy.
The website only works, if I set the ServerName with the https:// protocol although it is not needed / allowed according to the Apache documentation.
When removed, trying to open the website results in a redirect loop.
Here is my full question with more details, can't be posted here directly
GIST full question for StackExchange
based on this suggestion
Suggestion to add link to a Gist

Try setting it to something else invalid, like hppt://nonsense.example. Does it still work?

@Marcus Müller yes, it still works when setting it to something invalid or removing it all together. I have another setup where that doesn't work when the ServerName is removed, so I set it to ServerName www.smartreparatur.at:443 and ServerAlias smartreparatur:443 which works for the other setup.

so, then you saying "I need the https://" is wrong! You need the ServerName to not be (validly) specified. And that makes sense in a reverse proxy use case, when you think about it.

when I don't set it
ServerName www.smartreparatur.at:443
ServerAlias smartreparatur.at:443
I get the redirect error. My other application results in a redirect error regardles of the ServerName and ServerAlias being set or not but that might be an application error since a simple PHP script in the servers root folder can be access flawlessly in the Browser

I solved it by adding:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTPS:on]
</IfModule>

to the custom.conf so that the application can use use this info for further processing.
